# snowflake unique left join (asof join)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables: `trade` and `quotes`. I want to do `asof` join but `asof` join is not supported on snowflake. This is what I have so far:

```sql
create or replace temporary table trade (
   type varchar
  ,id varchar
  ,datetime TIMESTAMP_TZ
  ,price float
  ,volume int);
insert into trade values
    ('trade',1, '2020-01-06 09:00:01.329+09:00', 300, 1), 
    ('trade',1, '2020-01-06 09:00:45.500+09:00', 301, 2);
select * from trade;

create or replace temporary table quotes(
    type varchar
  , id varchar
  , datetime TIMESTAMP_TZ
  , ask float
  , bid float
);
insert into quotes values
    ('quote', 1, '2020-01-06 09:00:01.250+09:00', 300, 299), 
    ('quote', 1, '2020-01-06 09:00:01.399+09:00', 301, 299),
    ('quote', 1, '2020-01-06 09:00:01.421+09:00', 301, 300),    
    ('quote', 1, '2020-01-06 09:00:45.539+09:00', 302, 301);
select * from quotes;

select * from quotes as q
left join trade as t
on q.id = t.id and q.datetime >= t.datetime
qualify row_number() over(
    partition by q.id, q.datetime
    order by t.datetime desc)=1;
```

When we run this we get

```sql
TYPE    ID  DATETIME                        ASK BID TYPE    ID  DATETIME                    PRICE   VOLUME
quote   1   2020-01-06 09:00:01.250 +0900   300 299                 
quote   1   2020-01-06 09:00:01.399 +0900   301 299 trade   1   2020-01-06 09:00:01.329 +0900   300 1
quote   1   2020-01-06 09:00:01.421 +0900   301 300 trade   1   2020-01-06 09:00:01.329 +0900   300 1
quote   1   2020-01-06 09:00:45.539 +0900   302 301 trade   1   2020-01-06 09:00:45.500 +0900   301 2
```

There is duplicate left join in the third row. What I want is the the third row to have `NULL` for `price` and `volume`. Is there way we can perform a unique left join?

Comment: Why should the third row be NULLs  this is true `q.datetime >= t.datetime` and the `qualifier = 1` ?  are you expecting that the left join will only use a row once? (that's not how they work)

Comment: I'd like to do a 'unique' left join (if that's a thing). I'd like to know how I can make the third row null.

Comment: I don't think you can, perhaps you need to use lag(t.datetime) in an outer query within case expressions to suppress output from the left joined columns

Comment: but doens't `asof` join perform 'unique' left join?

Comment: This post talks about left asof, right asof, and full asof, https://blog.quasar.ai/timeseries-what-are-asof-joins

can you point to the source of "asof" that you wish to emulate.

Comment: but in essence, if you want to bind to a "close time" but not to a time that has already bound, you will need to define you bind direction.

Comment: the asof join I wish to emulate is https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/join/ (in `asof join usage` section)

Comment: so the logic is "find the most recent quote time and find the most recent trade that is before/equal" then go to the next quote time, if the most recent trade is already used, find one not used. and repeat over the set. It can be solved with a UDTF to carry the state, now thinking about the pure SQL version.

Comment: udtf would be trivial. I'm starting to think that this can't be done in pure sql..

Comment: I wrote a UDTF for AsOf joins but that can risk running out of UDF memory. There is a high-performance SQL-only approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75409949/how-to-do-an-as-of-join-in-sql-snowflake

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible approach, but I don't use snowflake, I have used Postgres for this example:

```
with cte as (
    select
       *
      , row_number() over( partition by qid, qdatetime order by d.datetime desc) as rn
    from (
        Select
            q.id qid 
          , q.datetime qdatetime
          , t.*
        from quotes as q
        left join trade as t on q.id = t.id and q.datetime >= t.datetime
        ) d
    )
SELECT * 
FROM quotes AS q
left join cte AS t on q.id = t.id and q.datetime = t.qdatetime and t.rn = 1
  and not exists (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM quotes q2 
  WHERE q2.id = q.id AND q2.datetime < q.datetime AND q2.datetime >= t.datetime
  ) 
order by q.uid, t.uid
```

| uid | type | id | datetime | ask | bid | qid | qdatetime | uid | type | id | datetime | price | volume | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | quote | 1 | 2020-01-06 09:00:01.25 | 300 | 299 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 2 | quote | 1 | 2020-01-06 09:00:01.399 | 301 | 299 | 1 | 2020-01-06 09:00:01.399 | 1 | trade | 1 | 2020-01-06 09:00:01.329 | 300 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | quote | 1 | 2020-01-06 09:00:01.421 | 301 | 300 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 4 | quote | 1 | 2020-01-06 09:00:45.539 | 302 | 301 | 1 | 2020-01-06 09:00:45.539 | 2 | trade | 1 | 2020-01-06 09:00:45.5 | 301 | 2 | 1 |

Please note I added a "uid" to each table

See https://dbfiddle.uk/LdYs-F6w

Comment: this gives me an error `Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated` on snowflake. Trying to see if i can convert it into snowsql

Comment: Then I am out of ideas. Inevitably someone will downvote this and when that happens I'll probably delete this - until then perhaps it will inspire some other approach that will work.

Comment: would it be possible to use your query within another layer of query, and in that you use lag() to detect if a join has been repeated and then via case expression you suppress those repeats in the final result?

Comment: the major problem, is in Row based SQL engines, you can do a per row look-up, snowflake want to do "build data" "join data" operations, thus to carry state, which is what this problem is doing, you need to use something that can carry state, like a UDTF

Answer (score 1):

Ok so here is a recursive CTE answer, and I hate it, BUT it works for this toy size dataset:

I put your two tables into a reduced form, and then didn't even carry most of the values, but that is all able to be added back in.

But the answer is still use a User Defined Table Function and carry the state there..

```
with recursive quotes(type, id, datetime, ask) as (
    select column1, column2, to_date(column3), column4 from values
    ('q', 1, '2020-01-03', 30), 
    ('q', 1, '2020-01-05', 31),
    ('q', 1, '2020-01-06', 32),    
    ('q', 1, '2020-01-07', 33)
), trade(type, id, datetime, price) as (
    select column1, column2, to_date(column3), column4 from values
    ('t', 1, '2020-01-04', 300), 
    ('t', 1, '2020-01-05', 301), 
    ('t', 1, '2020-01-07', 302)
), quotes_plus as (
    select 
        id
        ,datetime
        ,row_number() over(partition by id order by datetime desc) as rn
    from quotes
), rec_cte(id, datetime, match, rn) as (
    select 
        x.id, 
        x.datetime,
        t.datetime,
        x.rn
    from quotes_plus as x
    left join trade as t 
        on x.id = t.id 
            and x.datetime >= t.datetime
    where rn=1

    union all 

    select
        r.id,
        q.datetime,
        t.datetime,
        q.rn
    from rec_cte as r
    join quotes_plus as q
        on r.id = q.id 
            and r.rn + 1 = q.rn
    left join trade as t 
        on r.id = t.id 
            and q.id = t.id
            and q.datetime >= t.datetime
            and r.match > t.datetime
)
select *
from rec_cte
qualify row_number() over(partition by id, rn order by match desc nulls last)=1
;
```

gives:

| ID | DATETIME | MATCH | RN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-07 | 2020-01-07 | 1 |
| 1 | 2020-01-06 | 2020-01-05 | 2 |
| 1 | 2020-01-05 | 2020-01-04 | 3 |
| 1 | 2020-01-03 | null | 4 |

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so to do this in a UDTF, we will need to have the LEFT build all the rows that want to care about.

To avoid that join exploding, you should limit the joins, to some context that makes sense, which I will choose "same day".

this:

```
select 
    q.*
    ,t.*
from (select *, datetime::date as datetimeday from quotes) as q
left join (select *, datetime::date as datetimeday from trade) as t 
    on q.id = t.id
        and q.datetimeday = t.datetimeday
        and q.datetime >= t.datetime
order by q.id, q.datetime, t.datetime
```

Which give the answer you already have, but it you had trades from yesterday, those would not bind to todays quotes. The fine tuning of this filter is where your performance will be made/broken. But I would do the cast to date as a separate column inside a sub-select myself. And if you you want an N-hours, I would explode the data by N and still do an EQUI-JOIN.

So now we need a UDTF that does the carry of the state, of the ZIP join, the ASOF is doing, given Javascript only supports FLOATS we luckly can store epoch millisecond safely (as it's less that 2^53).

So this first UDTF shows us how it labels the rows.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ASOF_JOIN(qms float, tms float) RETURNS TABLE (cs float)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT AS
'{
  processRow: function (row, rowWriter) {
    if(row.TMS === undefined ){
        rowWriter.writeRow({CS: 0})
        return;
    }
    
    if(this.lqms === row.QMS ){
        // skip this row
        rowWriter.writeRow({CS: -2})
        return;
    }

    if( row.TMS < this.ltms )
    {
        // emit this row
        this.lqms = row.QMS;
        this.ltms = row.TMS;

        rowWriter.writeRow({CS: 1})
        return;
    }
    rowWriter.writeRow({CS: -1})
  },
  initialize: function() {
    this.lqms = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    this.ltms = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
  }
}';
```

used like:

```
select 
     q.* exclude datetimeday
    ,t.* exclude datetimeday
    ,x.*
from (select *, datetime::date as datetimeday from quotes) as q
left join (select *, datetime::date as datetimeday from trade) as t 
    on q.id = t.id
        and q.datetimeday = t.datetimeday
        and q.datetime >= t.datetime
join table(asof_join(date_part(epoch_millisecond, q.datetime)::float, date_part('epoch_millisecond', t.datetime)::float) 
    over(partition by q.id order by q.datetime desc, t.datetime desc)) as x
order by q.id, q.datetime, t.datetime
```

we get:

[image]

the rows, with a 0 are null input, the rows with a 1 the value of t.datetime is to be kept, where -2 are the rows we want to skip.

Thus we can change the UDF to do the skipping for us, and change the SQL to choose what datetime to use like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ASOF_JOIN(qms float, tms float) RETURNS TABLE (cs float)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT AS
'{
  processRow: function (row, rowWriter) {
    if(row.TMS === undefined ){
        rowWriter.writeRow({CS: 0})
        return;
    }
    
    if(this.lqms === row.QMS ){
        // skip this row
        //rowWriter.writeRow({CS: -2})
        return;
    }

    if( row.TMS < this.ltms )
    {
        // emit this row
        this.lqms = row.QMS;
        this.ltms = row.TMS;

        rowWriter.writeRow({CS: 1})
        return;
    }
    rowWriter.writeRow({CS: -1})
  },
  initialize: function() {
    this.lqms = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    this.ltms = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
  }
}';
```

```
select 
    q.* exclude datetimeday
    ,t.* exclude datetimeday
    ,iff(x.cs = 1, t.datetime, null) as cleaned_datetime
    --,x.*
from (select *, datetime::date as datetimeday from quotes) as q
left join (select *, datetime::date as datetimeday from trade) as t 
    on q.id = t.id
        and q.datetimeday = t.datetimeday
        and q.datetime >= t.datetime
join table(asof_join(date_part(epoch_millisecond, q.datetime)::float, date_part('epoch_millisecond', t.datetime)::float) 
    over(partition by q.id order by q.datetime desc, t.datetime desc)) as x
order by q.id, q.datetime, t.datetime
```

gives:

| TYPE | ID | DATETIME | ASK | BID | TYPE_2 | ID_2 | DATETIME_2 | PRICE | VOLUME | CLEANED_DATETIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| quote | 1 | 2020-01-06 09:00:01.250 +0900 | 300 | 299 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| quote | 1 | 2020-01-06 09:00:01.399 +0900 | 301 | 299 | trade | 1 | 2020-01-06 09:00:01.329 +0900 | 300 | 1 |  |
| quote | 1 | 2020-01-06 09:00:01.421 +0900 | 301 | 300 | trade | 1 | 2020-01-06 09:00:01.329 +0900 | 300 | 1 | 2020-01-06 09:00:01.329 +0900 |
| quote | 1 | 2020-01-06 09:00:45.539 +0900 | 302 | 301 | trade | 1 | 2020-01-06 09:00:45.500 +0900 | 301 | 2 | 2020-01-06 09:00:45.500 +0900 |

Answer (score -1):

Snowflake AS OF Joins are now in Public Preview. [Now in Public Preview, Snowflake’s ASOF JOIN functionality will accelerate your Time Series Analytics](https://medium.com/snowflake/now-in-public-preview-snowflakes-asof-join-functionality-will-accelerate-your-time-series-ba6cc3a8aad0). See also [AS OF JOIN - Snowflake Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/asof-join)