# Get the closest value if the data don't matched exactly in JOIN (SQL Snowflake)

Tags: sql, date, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to convert each local profit in local currency to another currency (EUR) by month with the last known RATE of each month or the closet RATE.

Here is my tables :

RATE_TABLE:

| RELATIVE_CURRENCY | LOCAL_CURRENCY | RATE | DATE_RATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EUR | AUD | 1.51 | 2023-02-03 |
| EUR | AUD | 1.52 | 2023-02-10 |
| EUR | USD | 1.1 | 2023-02-10 |
| EUR | GBP | 0.9 | 2022-12-10 |

PROFIT_TABLE :

| REGION | LOCAL_CURRENCY | LOCAL_PROFIT | PERIOD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| REGION_1 | AUD | 20 | 2023-02-20 |
| REGION_2 | USD | 40 | 2023-02-20 |
| REGION_3 | GBP | 15 | 2023-02-20 |

My Objective:

| REGION | LOCAL_CURRENCY | PROFIT_LOCAL | RELATIVE_CURRENCY | RATE | PERIOD | RATE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| REGION_1 | AUD | 20 | EUR | 1.52 | 2023-02-20 | 2023-02-10 |
| REGION_2 | USD | 40 | EUR | 1.1 | 2023-02-20 | 2023-02-10 |
| REGION_3 | GBP | 15 | EUR | 0.9 | 2023-02-20 | 2022-12-10 |

To complete my task I first select the last rate of each month and then JOIN on LOCAL CURRENCY and month and year (as I want one rate by month)
My code to achieve it :

```
WITH 
RATE_MONTH as (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT
            LOCAL_CURRENCY
            ,RATE
            ,DATE_RATE
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LOCAL_CURRENCY, YEAR(DATE_RATE), MONTH(DATE_RATE) ORDER BY DATE_RATE DESC) AS RowRank
        FROM RATE_TABLE
    ) sub
    WHERE RowRank = 1
    ORDER BY DATE_RATE DESC
)

SELECT 
     P.REGION
     ,P.PERIOD
     ,R.RATE
     ,P.LOCAL_CURRENCY
     ,R.RATE
     ,R.DATE_RATE
     ,P.LOCAL_PROFIT
FROM PROFIT_TABLE AS P
JOIN RATE_MONTH AS R ON P.LOCAL_CURRENCY =R.LOCAL_CURRENCY AND YEAR(P.PERIOD)=YEAR(R.DATE_RATE) AND MONTH(P.PERIOD)=MONTH(R.DATE_RATE)
WHERE PERIOD is not null
```

However the the table resulting from this code create don't retrieve value without matching data like REGION 3. What should I change/add to get the closet RATE to the missing values ?

Result:

| REGION | LOCAL_CURRENCY | PROFIT_LOCAL | RELATIVE_CURRENCY | RATE | PERIOD | RATE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| REGION_1 | AUD | 20 | EUR | 1.52 | 2023-02-20 | 2023-02-10 |
| REGION_2 | USD | 40 | EUR | 1.1 | 2023-02-20 | 2023-02-10 |
| REGION_3 | GBP | 15 | EUR | null | 2023-02-20 | null |

To recreate my samples :

```
CREATE TABLE RATE_TABLE (
    RELATIVE_CURRENCY VARCHAR(255),
    LOCAL_CURRENCY VARCHAR(255),
    RATE FLAOT,
    DATE_RATE DATE
)
INSERT INTO RATE_TABLE (RELATIVE_CURRENCY, LOCAL_CURRENCY,RATE, DATE_RATE)
VALUES 
    ('EUR', 'AUD', 20,2023-02-03),
    ('EUR', 'AUD', 1.52,2023-02-03),
    ('EUR', 'USD', 1.1,2023-02-03),
    ('EUR', 'GBP', 0.9,2022-12-10)
```

```
CREATE TABLE PROFIT_TABLE (
    REGION VARCHAR(255),
    LOCAL_CURRENCY VARCHAR(255),
    LOCAL_PROFIT FLAOT,
    PERIOD DATE
)
INSERT INTO PROFIT_TABLE (REGION, LOCAL_CURRENCY,LOCAL_PROFIT, PERIOD)
VALUES 
    ('REGION_1', 'AUD', 20,'2023-02-20'),
    ('REGION_2', 'USD', 40,'2023-02-20'),
    ('REGION_2', 'USD', 50,'2023-03-20'),
    ('REGION_3', 'GBP', 12,'2023-02-20'),
    ('REGION_1', 'USD', 11,'2023-02-20'),
    ('REGION_3', 'GBP', 15,'2023-01-20');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rowRank we need to partition by `RELATIVE_CURRENCY`, `LOCAL_CURRENCY` and order by  `DATE_RATE ASC` Then we get only rowRank = 1 which will be the closest RATE

```
WITH 
RATE_MONTH as (
   SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RELATIVE_CURRENCY, LOCAL_CURRENCY ORDER BY DATE_RATE DESC) AS RowRank
   FROM RATE_TABLE
)
SELECT *
from PROFIT_TABLE AS P
JOIN RATE_MONTH AS R ON P.LOCAL_CURRENCY =R.LOCAL_CURRENCY
WHERE RowRank = 1
```

To get the closest rate then this is a solution, we have to eliminate all rates that are higher than the profit period then we get the closest one which will be with rank = 1:

```
WITH 
RATE_MONTH as (
   SELECT P.*, R.RATE, R.DATE_RATE,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY REGION, PERIOD ORDER BY DATE_RATE DESC) AS RowRank
   FROM RATE_TABLE R
   JOIN PROFIT_TABLE P ON P.LOCAL_CURRENCY =R.LOCAL_CURRENCY
   WHERE PERIOD >= DATE_RATE
)
SELECT *
FROM RATE_MONTH
WHERE RowRank = 1;
```

Comment: I need the closest, not the latest but thanks for your solution, it is still interesting !

Comment: I have made an update can you check

Comment: With this I actually get the closest rate but only for each region once. When I have several time the region for different period (like I have update in my answer) I only get one period for a region.

Comment: Can you check again :)

Comment: It worked perfectly for my exemple ! But there is a new issues as I test it on my dataset. Sometimes there are rows with the same REGION and the same period  but with a profit on different CURRENCY. And this case it only keep one of them :(

I have edit my sample.

Comment: Try `PARTITION BY REGION, PERIOD, LOCAL_CURRENCY`

Comment: Thanks ! It was pretty obvious :')

Answer (score 2):

This is known as an AsOf join, and you only want to use Venn Diagram type joins for small tables. If you use a regular join for large tables there will be an intermediate cardinality explosion that will severely impact performance. If you have large tables you can use this method:

For large tables: [How to do an as-of-join in SQL (Snowflake)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75409949/how-to-do-an-as-of-join-in-sql-snowflake)

For small tables, you can use the `qualify` window function filter to do what you need here:

***Edit***: Added the "PERIOD" column to the partition by clause to calculate the closest RATE per REGION and PERIOD.

```
select * from PROFIT_TABLE P
    left join RATE_TABLE R on P.LOCAL_CURRENCY = R.LOCAL_CURRENCY
qualify row_number() 
        over (partition by REGION, PERIOD order by abs(DATE_RATE - PERIOD)) = 1;
```

Output:

| REGION | LOCAL_CURRENCY | LOCAL_PROFIT | PERIOD | RELATIVE_CURRENCY | LOCAL_CURRENCY_1 | RATE | DATE_RATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| REGION_1 | AUD | 20 | 2023-02-20 | EUR | AUD | 1.52 | 2023-02-10 |
| REGION_2 | USD | 40 | 2023-02-20 | EUR | USD | 1.1 | 2023-02-10 |
| REGION_3 | GBP | 15 | 2023-02-20 | EUR | GBP | 0.9 | 2022-12-10 |

The above SQL gets the closest rate in time, whether it's before or after the date. If you want only the most ***recent*** rate (backward in time) you can simply remove the absolute value, abs, from the order by clause on the qualify window function.

Comment: Actually your solution doewn't work when I have multiple region with the same name over different time periods as I edit in my question.

Comment: I only get the row by region where the period and the date rate are the closest.

Comment: Re: `doewn't work when I have multiple region with the same name over different time periods`, you can just add the PERIOD column to the partition by clause. I'll update the answer. If you need to keep all rows from that table, add whatever columns uniquely identify a row to your partition by clause.